# What application allows server hosting of audio files and streaming

Tags: streaming

There is a very large group of us who write and record music. The material is our own and not subject to any copyright. We often listen to each others music, but having to share them via email and then each having various copies is cumbersome.

Together, we have hundreds of songs, could even be up to 1000

We want to be able to upload this to some shared location (which isn't hosted by us) and be able to stream to our phones/computers.

We would also need to be able to "play all" as we often just listen to each others music on random.

We had hoped Google Play would suffice but it doesn't allow sharing of the personal library. And we don't want to share 1 single account.

Whilst we are not looking for a custom solution, we're happy to pay for a service.

Is there already software which exists for this?

Comment: I've read https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and also use the SE sites. I'm hoping this is on topic but as I wrote it, it felt odd due to SU never allowing software rec questions. I'm not sure if I'm actually asking for software or a solution :S

Comment: Use `unlisted` videos on youtube.  Share the URLs via email, build play lists to share, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to host, you can upload the files to say a service like [MixCloud](https://www.mixcloud.com/), after creating an account. You can then play directly via webrowser (laptop/computer or mobile phone) or via their mobile phone app. It allows you to create playlists of  material available or uploaded to the site.

But if you decide to host in future, then use [Music Player Daemon (MPD)](https://www.musicpd.org/), and play with any of the [MPD Clients](https://www.musicpd.org/clients/).