# Service to host, stream, and manage audio

Tags: audio, streaming, hosted

I'm working on a niche website that allows users to upload recorded audio and interact with it in many of the typical ways (add to playlist, favorite, etc). The SoundCloud API would be a perfect backend for this, but they [stopped allowing new apps a while ago](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform). I haven't been able to find any other service that matches what they did. I could just store the files on AWS or GCP and stream from there but that adds a lot of complexity I'd hope I could get from a media management service. Does anyone know of good alternatives? Happy to pay for this service.

I did find these two related questions:

- [Audio streaming service to broadcast songs and metadata](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83566/audio-streaming-service-to-broadcast-songs-and-metadata)
- [What application allows server hosting of audio files and streaming](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53340/what-application-allows-server-hosting-of-audio-files-and-streaming)

The former discusses mixcloud, which [explicitly disallows audio streaming](https://www.mixcloud.com/developers/#audio-streams) (see "audio streams" section), and the latter a server-side program that one can install to manage this. I'm looking for a hosted solution.

Comment: Hi. If i recall, mixcloud allows streaming if you have a Pro account. But how will that relate to your site? It seems like you are recreating mixcloud?

Comment: @ZZ - Definitely not recreating mixcloud, there's additional tools / capabilities for the specific audience. I'm focusing on the question here, not the business plan :)

Comment: What I really mean is you can talk to mixcloud since you want a hosted solution. Another one is iBroadcast. Then your users will be controlled by you on their site. Not sure there is a hosted service that let's you control many users or sub-users though. But ultimately, you may have to self-host. I use Navidrome. You can also use mpd.